# What does "|" notation mean in Mathematics?

Tags: notation

From
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec, I just ran into this weird looking "|" bar sign in a formula. What does this "|" mean?

> $J_\text{NEG} = \log Q_\theta(D=1 |w_t, h) +
>   k \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\tilde w \sim P_\text{noise}}
>      \left[ \log Q_\theta(D = 0 |\tilde w, h) \right]$

Comment: That's probably part of the definition of $Q_\theta$. At least, that would be my guess, without knowing anything about this specific use.

Comment: It's called Ket, I guess.

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like $Q_{\theta}$ is a probability distribution function, so the "$\mid$" would make it conditional (e.g., probability that $D=1$ given $w_t$ and $h$). Just a guess though.

Comment: Maybe "divides"? Or perhaps "such that".

Comment: See [Likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)

Comment: Yes, it seems this is a "conditional", so the definition of $Q_\theta$ has that in there, separating the arguments.  And therefore, no, this is not a "ket".